# WPF WrapPanel with some items having a height of *

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

### How do I make a WrapPanel with some items having a Height of *?

A deceptively simple question that I have been trying to solve. I want a control (or some XAML layout magickry) that behaves similar to a Grid that has some rows with a Height of *, but supports wrapping of columns. Hell; call it a WrapGrid. :)

Here's a mockup to visualize this. Imagine a grid defined as such:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="30">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="90">I'm star-sized.</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="30">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" MinHeight="90">I'm star-sized, too!</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" MinHeight="30">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" MinHeight="30">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

What I want this panel to do is **wrap an item into an additional column when the item can not get any smaller than its minHeight.** Here is a horrible MSPaint of some mockups I made detailing this process.

[image]

Recall from the XAML that the auto-sized buttons have minHeights of 30, and the star-sized buttons have minHeights of 90.

This mockup is just two grids side by side and I manually moved buttons around in the designer. Conceivably, this could be done programmatically and serve as a sort of convoluted solution to this.

**How can this be done?** I will accept any solution whether it's through xaml or has some code-behind (though I would prefer pure XAML if possible since xaml code behind is tougher to implement in IronPython).

*Updated with a bounty*

---

## Meleak's Solution

I managed to work out how to use Meleak's solution in my IPy app:

1) I compiled `WrapGridPanel.cs` into a DLL with `csc`:

```
C:\Projects\WrapGridTest\WrapGridTest>csc /target:library "WrapGridPanel.cs" /optimize /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationFramework.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationCore.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\WindowsBase.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xaml.dll"
```

**Update:** Added the `/optimize` switch, this nets a small performance increase

2) I added it to my application's xaml with the following line.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WrapGridTest;assembly=WrapGridPanel.dll"
```

This runs fine, but it breaks the designer. I can't really find a workaround for this yet, it looks to be a bug in VS2010. So as a workaround, in order to be able to use the designer, I just add the WrapGridPanel programmatically at runtime:

```
clr.AddReference("WrapGridPanel.dll")
from WrapGridTest import WrapGridPanel
wgp = WrapGridPanel()
```

**Slow performance when resizing**:

In my IronPython application, resizing the window containing this WrapGridPanel is slow and hitchy. Could the `RecalcMatrix()` algorithm be optimized? Could it perhaps be called less frequently? Maybe overriding `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`, as Nicholas suggested, would perform better?

**Update**: According to the VS2010 Instrumentation Profiler, 97% of the time spent in RecalcMatrix() is spent on Clear() and Add(). Modifying each element in-place would be a huge performance improvement. I'm taking a whack at it myself but it's always tough modifying someone else's code...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMTWU.png

### Update: Performance issues have been mostly ironed out. Thanks Meleak!

Here is a mockup of part of my actual application's UI, in XAML, if you wish to try it out.
http://pastebin.com/2EWY8NS0

Comment: You should be able to accept a code-behind solution and just reference that .Net type from withing your IronPython solution.

Comment: @siz: Yes, but I'm not sure how to get the code-behind 'compiled', so to speak, in order to be able to reference it from IPy.

Comment: @Aphex: I'll look into to your problems. It can be optimized for sure.

Comment: @Aphex: Updated my code with an optimized version. Should be much faster. I'll look at the other problem next

Comment: @Aphex: The problem is Margin, I didn't take that into account. I'll fix that

Comment: @Aphex: Fixed the Margin problem, the code is in the post. Try it out and let me know if it works better

Comment: Also, you asked if overriding `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` would perform better. It probably would, but I looked around in the existing Panels and they are pretty complex. Especially `Grid` which weights in with about 2000 lines of code

Comment: @Aphex: Did you try my updates? Any improvements?

Comment: @Meleak the Margin bug is fixed, no more overlapping! But it's still fairly slow. I'm stepping through it in the debugger and it seems that *every* time it's resized, *all* of the children get cleared from each Grid and *all* the child Grids get cleared from the WrapPanel. Then they get re-added. This seems super-expensive! Surely there's a way to modify them in place rather than executing two O(n²) operations...

Comment: @Aphex: Are you sure you used my latest code? That was the case before, but in my latest update I'm using a 2d list which checks if an update is necessary (meaning the elements needs to be moved around) and only then are they cleared and re-added to the UI. Check the method `SetupMatrix` (no UI involved), if it returns false the UI aren't touched

Comment: Yep, I used your latest code. I ran it through the performance analyzer to verify my theory, and it looks like it's true: http://i.imgur.com/tMTWU.png - approximately 97% of the time in RecalcMatrix is spent on Clear() and Add(). Modifying the elements in- place would be a huge performance improvement. I'm taking a whack at it myself but it's always tough modifying someone else's code...

Comment: @Aphex: How much are you resizing it? I can drag the Window Height up and down for several seconds and get maybe 20 to 30 resizes, doesn't show at all. As long as no element needs to move, no Clear or Add is done

Comment: @Aphex: New version again, only does Add/Clear/Remove if child needs to change parent Grid. Didn't have time to try it much but it should hopefully be faster

Comment: Nice! This version is smoother, with less hitching. According to the profiler, RecalcMatrix() now spends about 39% of its time on Remove(), 35% on Add(), and 13% on Clear(). I bet in-place modification would improve performance even more, but this is probably good enough for now! BTW, the way I tested it in the profiler, if you want to see for yourself, is by starting the program, grabbing the resizing corner, and dragging it around for a few seconds.

Comment: @Aphex: Ok, good to hear it's better at least because I'm starting to run out of optimization ideas here :) The last optimization I can think of is to do the same checking for the RowDefinitions, but that doesn't seem to be a bottleneck so we wouldn't get to much improvement out of it

Comment: @Aphex: I'm not sure what "in-place modification" mean?

Comment: Meaning, rather than `Clear()` ing all of the children and then re-`Add()` ing them with different attributes, just modify the existing children's attributes. That way you avoid the expensive `Clear()` and `Add()` operations.

Comment: @Aphex: Ah, ok. Well that's basically what's doing now. It is a `WrapPanel` with one `Grid` for each column (to get the * feature from `Grid`). But if a child have to be moved from the first column to the second, it has to be disconnected from its current parent `Grid`, before it can be placed in its new Parent `Grid` (Remove/Add).

Comment: @Aphex: Maybe this is clear to you, but I uploaded a picture that tries to explain what `WrapGridPanel` does :) It's a the bottom of my answer

Comment: That's a really good explanation, I looked over it again and now I do see that in the latest revision the children *are* modified in-place using `Grid.SetRow`, which was the idea! The only parts I don't understand yet is why you have the two `while` loops that call Add() and Clear() repeatedly...

Comment: @Aphex: If we had 3 Grids (Columns) and increased the Height so we only need 2 Grids (Columns), we delete the third Grid. Same if we decrease the Height so we now need 4 Grids, then we add one new. Both will never be run at the same resizing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**
Optimized `RecalcMatrix` so the UI is only rebuilt when needed. It doesn't touch the UI unless necessary so it should be much faster.

**Update Again**
Fixed problem when using `Margin`

Is think what you're looking at is basically a `WrapPanel` with Horizontal Orientation where every element in it is a 1 Column `Grid`. Each element in a Column then has a corresponding `RowDefinition` where the `Height` Property matches an attached property (`"WrapHeight"`) set on its Child. This Panel would have to be in a `Grid` itself, with `Height="*"` and `Width="Auto"` because the Children should be positioned by the available `Height` and not care about the available `Width`.

I made an implementation of this which I called a `WrapGridPanel`. You can use it like this

```
<local:WrapGridPanel>
    <Button MinHeight="30" local:WrapGridPanel.WrapHeight="Auto">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
    <Button MinHeight="90" local:WrapGridPanel.WrapHeight="*">I'm star-sized.</Button>
    <Button MinHeight="30" local:WrapGridPanel.WrapHeight="Auto">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
    <Button MinHeight="90" local:WrapGridPanel.WrapHeight="*">I'm star-sized, too!</Button>
    <Button MinHeight="30" local:WrapGridPanel.WrapHeight="Auto">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
    <Button MinHeight="30" local:WrapGridPanel.WrapHeight="Auto">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
</local:WrapGridPanel>
```

[image]

**WrapGridPanel.cs**

```
[ContentProperty("WrapChildren")] 
public class WrapGridPanel : Grid
{
    private WrapPanel m_wrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
    public WrapGridPanel()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Auto) } );
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star) } );
        Children.Add(m_wrapPanel);
        WrapChildren = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>();
        WrapChildren.CollectionChanged += WrapChildren_CollectionChanged;
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor actualHeightDescriptor
            = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(WrapGridPanel.ActualHeightProperty,
                                                        typeof(WrapGridPanel));
        if (actualHeightDescriptor != null)
        {
            actualHeightDescriptor.AddValueChanged(this, ActualHeightChanged);
        }
    }

    public static void SetWrapHeight(DependencyObject element, GridLength value)
    {
        element.SetValue(WrapHeightProperty, value);
    }
    public static GridLength GetWrapHeight(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (GridLength)element.GetValue(WrapHeightProperty);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> WrapChildren
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>)base.GetValue(WrapChildrenProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(WrapChildrenProperty, value); }
    }

    void ActualHeightChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecalcMatrix();
    }
    void WrapChildren_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RecalcMatrix();
    }

    List<List<FrameworkElement>> m_elementList = null;
    private bool SetupMatrix()
    {
        m_elementList = new List<List<FrameworkElement>>();
        double minHeightSum = 0;
        m_elementList.Add(new List<FrameworkElement>());
        int column = 0;
        if (WrapChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (FrameworkElement child in WrapChildren)
            {
                double tempMinHeight = 0.0;
                if (WrapGridPanel.GetWrapHeight(child).GridUnitType != GridUnitType.Star)
                {
                    tempMinHeight = Math.Max(child.ActualHeight, child.MinHeight) + child.Margin.Top + child.Margin.Bottom;
                }
                else
                {
                    tempMinHeight = child.MinHeight + child.Margin.Top + child.Margin.Bottom;
                }
                minHeightSum += tempMinHeight;
                if (minHeightSum > ActualHeight)
                {
                    minHeightSum = tempMinHeight;
                    m_elementList.Add(new List<FrameworkElement>());
                    column++;
                }
                m_elementList[column].Add(child);
            }
        }
        if (m_elementList.Count != m_wrapPanel.Children.Count)
        {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m_elementList.Count; i++)
        {
            List<FrameworkElement> columnList = m_elementList[i];
            Grid wrapGrid = m_wrapPanel.Children[i] as Grid;
            if (columnList.Count != wrapGrid.Children.Count)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void RecalcMatrix()
    {
        if (ActualHeight == 0 || SetupMatrix() == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        Binding heightBinding = new Binding("ActualHeight");
        heightBinding.Source = this;
        while (m_elementList.Count > m_wrapPanel.Children.Count)
        {
            Grid wrapGrid = new Grid();
            wrapGrid.SetBinding(Grid.HeightProperty, heightBinding);
            m_wrapPanel.Children.Add(wrapGrid);
        }
        while (m_elementList.Count < m_wrapPanel.Children.Count)
        {
            Grid wrapGrid = m_wrapPanel.Children[m_wrapPanel.Children.Count - 1] as Grid;
            wrapGrid.Children.Clear();
            m_wrapPanel.Children.Remove(wrapGrid);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m_elementList.Count; i++)
        {
            List<FrameworkElement> columnList = m_elementList[i];
            Grid wrapGrid = m_wrapPanel.Children[i] as Grid;
            wrapGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < columnList.Count; j++)
            {
                FrameworkElement child = columnList[j];
                GridLength wrapHeight = WrapGridPanel.GetWrapHeight(child);
                Grid.SetRow(child, j);
                Grid parentGrid = child.Parent as Grid;
                if (parentGrid != wrapGrid)
                {
                    if (parentGrid != null)
                    {
                        parentGrid.Children.Remove(child);
                    }
                    wrapGrid.Children.Add(child);
                }

                RowDefinition rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
                rowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(Math.Max(1, child.MinHeight), wrapHeight.GridUnitType);
                wrapGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition); 
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WrapHeightProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("WrapHeight",
                                                typeof(GridLength),
                                                typeof(WrapGridPanel),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Auto)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WrapChildrenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("WrapChildren",
                                        typeof(ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>),
                                        typeof(WrapGridPanel),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

**Update**
Fixed more than one star-sized column problem.
New sample app here: http://www.mediafire.com/?28z4rbd4pp790t2

**Update**
A picture that tries to explain what `WrapGridPanel` does

[image]

Comment: Very cool! I downloaded your test code and tried it out. I only found one bug: it appears that star-sized elements with a MinHeight higher than the smallest MinHeight are ignored. That is to say, if there are a few star-sized objects with a MinHeight of 90, then a star-sized object with a MinHeight of 180 will be treated as if it had a MinHeight of 90, and will be overlapped. Here's a screenshot showing this. I've labeled each star sized element with its MinHeight: http://i.imgur.com/H9GqU.png

Comment: @Aphex: Didn't notice that one! I'll look into it

Comment: @Aphex: The problem was that every star-sized row got * as Height, it should be 90*, 180* etc. I updated my example. I've upload a new sample-app as well

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your hard work! Now to figure out how to use this in my IronPython app...

Comment: @Aphex: Sure thing! Good luck with the IronPython stuff :)

Comment: OK, I managed to work out how to use this in my IPy app - however there are two issues I've run into. Please see my main post!

Comment: Thanks for the picture, that really sheds some light on the implementation. Turns out my mockup that I made for the original post was really close to this idea ;)

Comment: @Aphex: Yes, just looking at someone else's code doesn't always give you a clear picture of what's going on, and yes, it was indeed pretty close :)

Comment: I just started using this custom `WrapPanel`, but why is it being oriented as Vertical by default. How can I change this behavior to be horizontal panel?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard panel implementation that behave like you want. So, your best option is probably to roll your own.

It may sound intimidating at first, but it's not that difficult.

You can probably dig the `WrapPanel` source code somewhere (mono?), and adapt it to your need.

You don't need columns and rows. All you need is an attached `Size` property:

```
<StuffPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button StuffPanel.Size="Auto" MinHeight="30">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
    <Button StuffPanel.Size="*" MinHeight="90">I'm star-sized.</Button>
    <Button StuffPanel.Size="Auto"  MinHeight="30">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
    <Button StuffPanel.Size="*" MinHeight="90">I'm star-sized, too!</Button>
    <Button StuffPanel.Size="Auto"  MinHeight="30">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
    <Button StuffPanel.Size="Auto" MinHeight="30">I'm auto-sized.</Button>
</StuffPanel>
```

Comment: This got me thinking. Is there a way to derive a WrapPanel that supports a Height dependency property that accepts *?

Comment: There is no reason to derive from it, as WrapPanel does little except overriding `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` (these two methods contains the "layout behaviour").

Comment: Okay, then how do I implement this `StuffPanel`?

Comment: I will award the bounty to an answer that can give me some idea on how to implement a WrapPanel that supports this behavior. That `Size` property is a nice syntax idea, but how is it implemented?